# React Native: Style not responding to state change

Tags: reactjs, svg, react-native

I'm using the [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg) module to render svg icons. What I want is, when the user taps on the icon, the icon should change its colour. Because I can have multiple icons, I assign a unique number to each of them. Then for the style prop, I check if the icon's id is within the state, and choose colour accordingly. I'm updating the state correctly, but on re-rendering the icon is not updating.

```
this.state = {favoritedCalcs: []}

addToFavorite(calcId) {
    let favoritedCalcs = Object.assign([], this.state.favoritedCalcs)
    let updatedFavoritedCalcs

    if (this.isFavorite(calcId)) {
      updatedFavoritedCalcs = favoritedCalcs.filter((id) => {
        return calcId !== id
      })
    } else {
      updatedFavoritedCalcs = favoritedCalcs.concat(calcId)
    }

    this.setState({
      favoritedCalcs: updatedFavoritedCalcs
    })
  }

  isFavorite(calcId) {
    let favoritedCalcs = this.state.favoritedCalcs
    console.log(favoritedCalcs.indexOf(calcId) !== -1)
    if (favoritedCalcs.indexOf(calcId) !== -1) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }

render() {
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.addToFavorite(calc.favorite_id)}>
      <Svg viewBox="0 0 41 39.23" height="20" width="20">
          <Path    d="M21.36,2.13,25.23,14a.91.91,0,0,0,.86.63h12.5a.91.91,0,0,1,.53,1.64L29,23.63a.91.91,0,0,0-.33,1l3.86,11.89a.91.91,0,0,1-1.4,1L21,30.2a.91.91,0,0,0-1.07,0L9.85,37.55a.91.91,0,0,1-1.4-1l3.86-11.89a.91.91,0,0,0-.33-1L1.88,16.29a.91.91,0,0,1,.53-1.64h12.5a.91.91,0,0,0,.86-.63L19.64,2.13A.91.91,0,0,1,21.36,2.13Z"
            fill={this.isFavorite(calc.favorite_id) ? "#FFB600" : "#1bb393"}
          />
      </Svg>
  </TouchableOpacity>
}
```

Comment: what is the value of calc.favorite_id

Comment: how you assign the unique number?

Comment: Try this https://snack.expo.io/SkjY5Oeob, it implements a similar logic, your code should be working. The only suggestion would be put a `debugger` inside render function, see if it gets triggered correctly and the state is set correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, realized that it was updating and changing the style. I'm using a FlatList to render the icons, but because there's at least 300 of them, when I update state, it'll re-render each row component. I applied shouldItemUpdate prop and that definitely improved performance.

Comment: @jamesvphan just a suggestion, don't set the initial state like that, rather set it inside the constructor of your component as suggested in [the official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using FlatList to render each row, when I try to update the style for one row, React will attempt to re-render all the rows.  I applied shouldItemUpdate prop to FlatList and that improved performance and now rows update style with state change

```
<FlatList 
    shouldItemUpdate={(prev, next) => {return prev.item !== next.item}}
    initialNumToRender={30}
/>
```